# WSL closes abruptly when I execute a windows command after sourcing a bash script containing the option `set -e`

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Steps to reproduce.

Please note, I am using WSL (Ubuntu 18) version 1.
Windows version 1909 (OS Build 18363.900).

1. Create a dummy bash script `foo.sh` containing the option `set -e`.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

pwd
```

2. Execute the following commands in WSL.

```
$ source foo.sh
$ explorer.exe .
```

After I execute the second command `explorer.exe .` WSL closes abruptly.

Comment: `set -e` terminates the shell, if a command returns a value different from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it out, and indeed: When I run `explorer`, the explorer Windows opens in the background, and the process which starts the Explorer **returns with exit code 1**. I don't know why Microsoft in their infinite wisdom decided to implement it in this way.

Of course, having `set -e` in an interactive shell is insane. I suggest to unset it. If, the scenario is not an interactive shell (this is not entirely clear from your question), but you run the commands from inside a script, and you do want to stick with `-e`, start the explorer with

```
explorer.exe || true
```

to keep the shell running.